# Connecting metadata api using ajax toolkit

Tags: visualforce, javascript, metadata-api, ajax-toolkit

I am trying to call the metadata api call -reterive in the javascript in vf page.
I am getting error
load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
<apex:page controller="depoloymentsheet">
  <apex:form >
  <script src="https://xxxxxx.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js"  
          type="text/javascript">
  sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';
  </script>
  <script>
  function compextract() {
    var myList = new Array();
    myList = '{!Apilist}';
    var Res=sforce.connection.retrieve(myList);
    alert(res);
  }
  </script>
  <apex:facet name="header">Deployment Tool</apex:facet>
  <apex:commandButton onclick="compextract();" value="Reterive" id="theButton"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class depoloymentsheet { 
    public List<release__c> Apilist{get;set;} 
    public depoloymentsheet() { 
        Apilist=[SELECT Id,ObjectApiname__c FROM release__c]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in myList? That's probably where your problem lies.

Comment: Also, this won't work:  var Res=sforce.connection.retrieve(myList);
    alert(res); - Javascript is case sensitive, so your alert will show nothing.

Comment: "Mylist" is the java array which hold the component api names.Apilist is list in apex class which will query the api names in the object called release.